# scipy giving different answer when feeding array vs feeding element by element

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I have this code snippet:

```
print(np.sqrt(scipy.stats.chi2.ppf(1-prob,1)))

for i in prob:
    print(np.sqrt(scipy.stats.chi2.ppf(1-i,1)))
```

I thought these should give me the same answer but the answer I get out are:

`[0. inf 2.27834698 0.22780442 2.21905125]`

and

```
0.0
6.1833132853181185
2.2783471062868474
0.22780441954248226
2.219051610822544
```

printing prob gives me `[1.0000000e+00 6.2769967e-10 2.2705905e-02 8.1979829e-01 2.6483214e-02]`, which is very weird as when I copy this array and do the top command in console python, I can get the correct answer, but running the script always gives me the inf.

I am running python 3.9.7, scipy 1.7.3, numpy 1.21.4. The prob.dtype gives me float32, printing the type of each elements in the array individually also gives me float32.

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the values shown in the question, `prob` is:

```
In [155]: prob = np.array([1.0000000e+00, 6.2769967e-10, 2.2705905e-02, 8.1979829e-01, 2.6483214e-02], dtype=np.float32)

In [156]: prob
Out[156]: 
array([1.0000000e+00, 6.2769967e-10, 2.2705905e-02, 8.1979829e-01,
       2.6483214e-02], dtype=float32)
```

The value that you give to `scipy.stats.chi2.ppf` is actually `1 - prob`, and that subtraction is where the problem occurs:

```
In [174]: 1 - prob
Out[174]: 
array([0.        , 1.        , 0.9772941 , 0.18020171, 0.97351676],
      dtype=float32)
```

Note that the second value in the result is 1.0.  That is because `6.2769967e-10` is much smaller than the "machine epsilon" for `np.float32`, which is about `1.19e-7`.  In other words, `6.27e-10` is smaller than the resolution of the `np.float32` representation around `1.0`. When you pass `1 - prob` to the `ppf()` method, the result for the input value `1.0` is `inf` (and that is correct).

As you already noted in your answer, you can avoid the problem by casting `prob` to `np.float64`.  An alternative method to avoid the problem is to  use `isf(prob, 1)` instead of `ppf(1 - prob, 1)`:

```
In [177]: print(np.sqrt(scipy.stats.chi2.isf(prob, 1)))
[0.         6.18331329 2.27834711 0.22780442 2.21905161]
```

`isf` is the *inverse survival function*.  That expression is mathematically equivalent to `ppf(1 - prob, 1)`, but it avoids the subtraction that causes the extreme loss of precision.

Answer (score 1):

I casted prob as a float64 array and it worked. It looks like there's something funny going on with the precision in float32.